# LCR circuit power transfer from driving source to the driven oscillator

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, oscillators, inductance

For a LCR circuit,the power transferred from the driving source to the driven oscillator is $P=I^2 Z \cos \phi$, is it necessary that

1. the power factor $\cos \phi \ge 0$, $P \ge 0$?
2. the driving force can give no energy to the oscillator $(P=0)$ in some cases?
3. the driving force cannot syphon out $(P<0)$ the energy out of the oscillator?

Is it impossible to transfer power without fulfilling these conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. This follows by considering where exactly this relationship comes from, namely $P=I^2R$. In the more general case where we have an impedence it is still the case that power is only dissipated in resistive elements, and we happen to have the relationship $R = Z cos \phi $ (just draw out the phasors).

Since $R \geq 0 $ all your points follow. We can make $P=0$ if we have $R=0$ i.e. we have a purely oscillatory $LC$ circuit.